# Place a Canvas Circle within the nearest Canvas Circle Point

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-canvas, motionevent

I am currently developing a tree shaped structure using Canvas Circles and I have almost brought about the layouts using Canvas but facing problem while implementing Drag and Drop in Canvas. The code is as follows for better understanding :

```
private HashSet<CircleArea> mCircles = new HashSet<CircleArea>(CIRCLES_LIMIT);
    private SparseArray<CircleArea> mCirclePointer = new SparseArray<CircleArea>(CIRCLES_LIMIT);
     private static class CircleArea {
            int radius;
            int centerX;
            int centerY;

            CircleArea(int centerX, int centerY, int radius) {
                this.radius = radius;
                this.centerX = centerX;
                this.centerY = centerY;
            }

            public int getCenterX()
            {
                return centerX;
            }
            public int getCenterY()
            {
                return centerY;
            }

            public int getRadius()
            {
                return radius;
            }


            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Circle[" + centerX + ", " + centerY + ", " + radius + "]";
            }
        }

    private void init(final Context ct) {

            Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;
            System.out.println("Width is " + width + "Height is " + height);
            scrWidth = width;
            scrHeight = height;

        }
 @Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas canv) {

       // setWillNotDraw(false);

            for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < latitude_0.length; j++) {
                        x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude_0[j]));
                        y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude_0[j]));
                        mCircles.add(new CircleArea(x,y,RADIUS_LIMIT));

                    }

                } else if (i == 1) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < latitude_1.length; k++) {
                        x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude_1[k]));
                        y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude_1[k]));
                        mCircles.add(new CircleArea(x,y,RADIUS_LIMIT));



                    }
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < latitude_2.length; l++) {
                        x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude_2[l]));
                        y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude_2[l]));
                        mCircles.add(new CircleArea(x,y,RADIUS_LIMIT));


                    }
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < latitude_3.length; l++) {
                        x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude_3[l]));
                        y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude_3[l]));
                        mCircles.add(new CircleArea(x, y, RADIUS_LIMIT));

                    }
                } else if (i == 4) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < latitude_4.length; l++) {
                        x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude_4[l]));
                        y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude_4[l]));
                        mCircles.add(new CircleArea(x,y,RADIUS_LIMIT));


                    }
                }else if (i == 5) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < latitude_5.length; l++) {
                        x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude_5[l]));
                        y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude_5[l]));
                        mCircles.add(new CircleArea(x,y,RADIUS_LIMIT));


                    }
                }else if (i == 6) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < latitude_6.length; l++) {
                        x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude_6[l]));
                        y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude_6[l]));
                        mCircles.add(new CircleArea(x,y,RADIUS_LIMIT));


                    }
                }

            }


                for (CircleArea circle : mCircles) {

                    canv.drawCircle(circle.getCenterX(),circle.getCenterY(),RADIUS_LIMIT, mCirclePaint);
                }




      //  invalidate();;
    }
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;

        CircleArea touchedCircle;
        int xTouch;
        int yTouch;
        int pointerId;
        int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();

        // get touch event coordinates and make transparent circle from it
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                xTouch = (int) event.getX(0);
                yTouch = (int) event.getY(0);

                        touchedCircle = obtainTouchedCircle(xTouch, yTouch);
                        touchedCircle.centerX = xTouch;
                        touchedCircle.centerY = yTouch;
                        mCirclePointer.put(event.getPointerId(0), touchedCircle);


                invalidate();
                handled = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                Log.w(TAG, "Pointer down");
                // It secondary pointers, so obtain their ids and check circles
                pointerId = event.getPointerId(actionIndex);

                xTouch = (int) event.getX(actionIndex);
                yTouch = (int) event.getY(actionIndex);

                // check if we've touched inside some circle
                for(CircleArea circle: mCircles)
                {
                    touchedCircle = obtainTouchedCircle(circle.getCenterX(), circle.getCenterY());
                    mCirclePointer.put(pointerId, touchedCircle);
                    touchedCircle.centerX = circle.getCenterX();
                    touchedCircle.centerY = circle.getCenterY();

                }

                invalidate();
                handled = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

                Log.w(TAG, "Move");

                for (actionIndex = 0; actionIndex < pointerCount; actionIndex++) {
                    // Some pointer has moved, search it by pointer id
                    pointerId = event.getPointerId(actionIndex);

                    for(CircleArea circle: mCircles)
                    {
                        xTouch = (int) event.getX(actionIndex);
                        yTouch = (int) event.getY(actionIndex);
                        float dx = xTouch - circle.getCenterX();
                        float dy = yTouch - circle.getCenterY();

                        float r = FloatMath.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

                        touchedCircle = mCirclePointer.get(pointerId);

                        if (null != touchedCircle) {
                            touchedCircle.centerX = xTouch;
                            touchedCircle.centerY = yTouch;
                        }
                    }

                }
                invalidate();
                handled = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //clearCirclePointer();
                invalidate();
                handled = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // not general pointer was up
                pointerId = event.getPointerId(actionIndex);

                mCirclePointer.remove(pointerId);
                // invalidate();
                handled = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                handled = true;
                break;

            default:
                // do nothing
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event) || handled;
    }
   private CircleArea obtainTouchedCircle(final int xTouch, final int yTouch) {
        CircleArea touchedCircle = getTouchedCircle(xTouch, yTouch);

        if (null == touchedCircle) {

            touchedCircle = new CircleArea(xTouch, yTouch, RADIUS_LIMIT);



        }

        return touchedCircle;
    }

    private CircleArea getTouchedCircle(final int xTouch, final int yTouch) {
        CircleArea touched = null;

        for (CircleArea circle : mCircles) {
            if ((circle.centerX - xTouch) * (circle.centerX - xTouch) + (circle.centerY - yTouch) * (circle.centerY - yTouch) <= circle.radius * circle.radius) {
                touched = circle;
                break;
            }
        }

        return touched;
    }
```

I am well aware of the shabby code that I've written but highly helpless to generate a mathematical calculation on how to place the dragged circle to the nearest available canvas circle. Below depicted is a screenshot which helps in more understanding.

**Points to be noted :**
The function `obtainTouchedCircle` and `getTouchedCircle` are vital. 
The `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` helps me in moving a circle but what it does is that it generates a new circle with the same dimensions every time which is totally fine but when a user drags and drops in somewhere, it should get placed in the nearest available circle.

Consider the below image where the yellow circles need to be moved around and placed in the blue circles according to the user's wish. That is my objective.

If someone can help me with the calculation on how I should figure out the nearest available circle while dragging would be of great help !!!! Thanks in advance.

[image]